Adding a customized End-effector to an UR Robot
Config

Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy
Ros HUMBLE
gazebo 11.10.2

Context
I've try last few days to put a customized End-effector (EE) to a UR10e (Visual + collision), so I can see it and work with it on gazebo and rviz (with moveit). However, Moveit seems to not work anymore with the EE.
Bug
I've specify fixed joint with wrist_3_link, flange and tool0 but still got collision. I've also tried independantly wrist_3_link, tool0 and flange; but I do not understand why I am still getting collision ...


What I did
I've add the EE corresponding .stl and .dae in /sr_description/meshes/ur_10e/collision/welding_tool_only.stl and /ur_description/meshes/ur10e/visual/welding_tool_only.dae.
Then, I edited the ur_macro.xacro as following :
<!-- My end effector -->
<link name="${tf_prefix}end_effector">
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="file://$(find sr_description)/meshes/ur10e/visual/welding_tool_only.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="file://$(find sr_description)/meshes/ur10e/collision/welding_tool_only.stl"/>
          <!-- <box size="0.05 0.05 0.05"/> -->
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
        <mass value="0.5"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <inertia
          ixx="0.001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
          iyy="0.001" iyz="0.0" 
          izz="0.001"/>
      </inertial>
    </link>

<!-- Joint between tool0 and end_effector -->
<joint name="${tf_prefix}tool0-end_effector" type="fixed">
<parent link="${tf_prefix}tool0"/>
    <child link="${tf_prefix}end_effector"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<!-- Joint between wrist_3 and end_effector -->
<joint name="${tf_prefix}wrist_3_link-end_effector" type="fixed">
<parent link="${tf_prefix}wrist_3_link"/>
    <child link="${tf_prefix}end_effector"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<!-- Joint between flange and end_effector -->
<joint name="${tf_prefix}flange-end_effector" type="fixed">
<parent link="${tf_prefix}flange"/>
    <child link="${tf_prefix}end_effector"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>


NB : The xml isn't well indented here Idk why but trust me it is in my xacro file.
After colcon building the project, I can now run the following command :
ros2 launch sr_simulation_gazebo sr_sim_moveit.launch.py 

If someone have a good tutorial on how adding a customized EE in ROS2, and ideally to an UR robot, would be very appreciated ! Thanks !

If you're getting collisions between two links that are adjacent, you should disable their collision in the .srdf file, for example <disable_collisions link1="flange" link2="${prefix}wrist_1_link" reason="Adjacent" />. The existing .srdf also should already include examples!

Hey ! Ty for your answer, but this is not working. Again Gazebo and rviz are launching well, but still it assume a collision between the flange and EE. I've also tried to put a diseable_collision between EE and all the robot links, still doesn't work ...

Can you add your .srdf file to the question?

I've partially fix the issue. By putting, meshes of my welding tool in the section
<link name="${tf_prefix}tool0"> :
    <link name="${tf_prefix}tool0">
    <xacro:get_visual_params name="tool0" type="visual_offset"/>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${visual_params}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <xacro:get_mesh name="tool0" type="visual"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${visual_params}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <xacro:get_mesh name="tool0" type="collision"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>

and
 <joint name="${tf_prefix}zivid-tool0" type="fixed">
      <!-- default toolframe - X+ left, Y+ up, Z+ front -->
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <parent link="${tf_prefix}tool0"/>
      <child link="${tf_prefix}zivid"/>
 </joint>

It fixed the problem with the collision between welding tool and flange; but I need to mention that everything was natif code, I just put this specific section :
<xacro:get_visual_params name="tool0" type="visual_offset"/>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${visual_params}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <xacro:get_mesh name="tool0" type="visual"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${visual_params}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <xacro:get_mesh name="tool0" type="collision"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>

under tool0 link.
Still if I try to put now a camera (zivid) on my welding tool, I got same problem of collision even with the <disable_collisions link1="${tf_prefix}zivid" link2="${tf_prefix}tool0" />
I do not understand what is different bewtween the tool0-flange joint (that is working well now) and the zivid-tool0 joint.
Here is the full code (Interesting part is at the end of it):
NB : Again alignment of the xml is badly written here but trust me, it is okay in my code.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://wiki.ros.org/xacro">
  <!--
    Base UR robot series xacro macro.

    NOTE this is NOT a URDF. It cannot directly be loaded by consumers
    expecting a flattened '.urdf' file. See the top-level '.xacro' for that
    (but note that .xacro must still be processed by the xacro command).

    This file models the base kinematic chain of a UR robot, which then gets
    parameterised by various configuration files to convert it into a UR3(e),
    UR5(e), UR10(e) or UR16e.

    NOTE the default kinematic parameters (i.e., link lengths, frame locations,
    offsets, etc) do not correspond to any particular robot. They are defaults
    only. There WILL be non-zero offsets between the Forward Kinematics results
    in TF (i.e., robot_state_publisher) and the values reported by the Teach
    Pendant.

    For accurate (and robot-specific) transforms, the 'kinematics_parameters_file'
    parameter MUST point to a .yaml file containing the appropriate values for
    the targeted robot.

    If using the UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver, follow the steps
    described in the readme of that repository to extract the kinematic
    calibration from the controller and generate the required .yaml file.

    Main author of the migration to yaml configs Ludovic Delval.

    Contributors to previous versions (in no particular order)

     - Denis Stogl
     - Lovro Ivanov
     - Felix Messmer
     - Kelsey Hawkins
     - Wim Meeussen
     - Shaun Edwards
     - Nadia Hammoudeh Garcia
     - Dave Hershberger
     - G. vd. Hoorn
     - Philip Long
     - Dave Coleman
     - Miguel Prada
     - Mathias Luedtke
     - Marcel Schnirring
     - Felix von Drigalski
     - Felix Exner
     - Jimmy Da Silva
     - Ajit Krisshna N L
     - Muhammad Asif Rana
  -->

  <xacro:include filename="$(find sr_description)/urdf/inc/ur_transmissions.xacro" />
  <xacro:include filename="$(find sr_description)/urdf/inc/ur_common.xacro" />

  <xacro:macro name="ur_robot" params="
    name
    tf_prefix
    parent
    *origin
    joint_limits_parameters_file
    kinematics_parameters_file
    physical_parameters_file
    visual_parameters_file
    generate_ros2_control_tag:=true
    transmission_hw_interface:=hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface
    safety_limits:=false
    safety_pos_margin:=0.15
    safety_k_position:=20
    use_fake_hardware:=false
    fake_sensor_commands:=false
    sim_gazebo:=false
    sim_ignition:=false
    headless_mode:=false
    initial_positions:=${dict(shoulder_pan_joint=0.0,shoulder_lift_joint=-1.57,elbow_joint=0.0,wrist_1_joint=-1.57,wrist_2_joint=0.0,wrist_3_joint=0.0)}
    use_tool_communication:=false
    tool_voltage:=0
    tool_parity:=0
    tool_baud_rate:=115200
    tool_stop_bits:=1
    tool_rx_idle_chars:=1.5
    tool_tx_idle_chars:=3.5
    tool_device_name:=/tmp/ttyUR
    tool_tcp_port:=54321
    robot_ip:=0.0.0.0
    script_filename:=to_be_filled_by_ur_robot_driver
    output_recipe_filename:=to_be_filled_by_ur_robot_driver
    input_recipe_filename:=to_be_filled_by_ur_robot_driver
    reverse_port:=50001
    script_sender_port:=50002
    reverse_ip:=0.0.0.0
    script_command_port:=50004
    trajectory_port:=50003
    non_blocking_read:=true
    keep_alive_count:=2"

    >

    <!-- Load configuration data from the provided .yaml files -->
    <xacro:read_model_data
      joint_limits_parameters_file="${joint_limits_parameters_file}"
  kinematics_parameters_file="${kinematics_parameters_file}"
      physical_parameters_file="${physical_parameters_file}"
  visual_parameters_file="${visual_parameters_file}"
      force_abs_paths="${sim_gazebo or sim_ignition}"/>


    <xacro:if value="${generate_ros2_control_tag}">
  <!-- ros2 control include -->
  <xacro:include filename="$(find sr_description)/urdf/ur.ros2_control.xacro" />
      <!-- ros2 control instance -->
      <xacro:ur_ros2_control
        name="${name}"
    use_fake_hardware="${use_fake_hardware}"
        initial_positions="${initial_positions}"
    fake_sensor_commands="${fake_sensor_commands}"
        headless_mode="${headless_mode}"
    sim_gazebo="${sim_gazebo}"
        sim_ignition="${sim_ignition}"
    script_filename="${script_filename}"
        output_recipe_filename="${output_recipe_filename}"
    input_recipe_filename="${input_recipe_filename}"
        tf_prefix="${tf_prefix}"
    hash_kinematics="${kinematics_hash}"
        robot_ip="${robot_ip}"
    use_tool_communication="${use_tool_communication}"
        tool_voltage="${tool_voltage}"
    tool_parity="${tool_parity}"
        tool_baud_rate="${tool_baud_rate}"
    tool_stop_bits="${tool_stop_bits}"
        tool_rx_idle_chars="${tool_rx_idle_chars}"
    tool_tx_idle_chars="${tool_tx_idle_chars}"
        tool_device_name="${tool_device_name}"
    tool_tcp_port="${tool_tcp_port}"
        reverse_port="${reverse_port}"
    script_sender_port="${script_sender_port}"
        reverse_ip="${reverse_ip}"
    script_command_port="${script_command_port}"
        trajectory_port="${trajectory_port}"
    non_blocking_read="${non_blocking_read}"
        keep_alive_count="${keep_alive_count}"
        />
    </xacro:if>

    <!-- Add URDF transmission elements (for ros_control) -->
    <!--<xacro:ur_arm_transmission prefix="${prefix}" hw_interface="${transmission_hw_interface}" />-->
    <!-- Placeholder for ros2_control transmission which don't yet exist -->

    <!-- links -  main serial chain -->
    <link name="${tf_prefix}base_link"/>
       
    <link name="${tf_prefix}base_link_inertia">
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 ${pi}"/>
        <geometry>
          <xacro:get_mesh name="base" type="visual"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 ${pi}"/>
    <geometry>
      <xacro:get_mesh name="base" type="collision"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  <xacro:cylinder_inertial radius="${base_inertia_radius}" length="${base_inertia_length}" mass="${base_mass}">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      </xacro:cylinder_inertial>
    </link>
    <link name="${tf_prefix}shoulder_link">
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 ${pi}"/>
        <geometry>
          <xacro:get_mesh name="shoulder" type="visual"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 ${pi}"/>
    <geometry>
      <xacro:get_mesh name="shoulder" type="collision"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  <inertial>
    <mass value="${shoulder_mass}"/>
        <origin rpy="${shoulder_inertia_rotation}" xyz="${shoulder_cog}"/>
        <inertia
            ixx="${shoulder_inertia_ixx}"
        ixy="${shoulder_inertia_ixy}"
            ixz="${shoulder_inertia_ixz}"
        iyy="${shoulder_inertia_iyy}"
            iyz="${shoulder_inertia_iyz}"
        izz="${shoulder_inertia_izz}"
        />
      </inertial>    </link>
    <link name="${tf_prefix}upper_arm_link">
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 ${shoulder_offset}" rpy="${pi/2} 0 ${-pi/2}"/>
        <geometry>
          <xacro:get_mesh name="upper_arm" type="visual"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${shoulder_offset}" rpy="${pi/2} 0 ${-pi/2}"/>
    <geometry>
      <xacro:get_mesh name="upper_arm" type="collision"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  <inertial>
    <mass value="${upper_arm_mass}"/>
        <origin rpy="${upper_arm_inertia_rotation}" xyz="${upper_arm_cog}"/>
        <inertia
            ixx="${upper_arm_inertia_ixx}"
        ixy="${upper_arm_inertia_ixy}"
            ixz="${upper_arm_inertia_ixz}"
        iyy="${upper_arm_inertia_iyy}"
            iyz="${upper_arm_inertia_iyz}"
        izz="${upper_arm_inertia_izz}"
        />
      </inertial>
    </link>
    <link name="${tf_prefix}forearm_link">
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 ${elbow_offset}" rpy="${pi/2} 0 ${-pi/2}"/>
        <geometry>
          <xacro:get_mesh name="forearm" type="visual"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${elbow_offset}" rpy="${pi/2} 0 ${-pi/2}"/>
    <geometry>
      <xacro:get_mesh name="forearm" type="collision"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  <inertial>
    <mass value="${forearm_mass}"/>
        <origin rpy="${forearm_inertia_rotation}" xyz="${forearm_cog}"/>
        <inertia
            ixx="${forearm_inertia_ixx}"
        ixy="${forearm_inertia_ixy}"
            ixz="${forearm_inertia_ixz}"
        iyy="${forearm_inertia_iyy}"
            iyz="${forearm_inertia_iyz}"
        izz="${forearm_inertia_izz}"
        />
      </inertial>
    </link>
    <link name="${tf_prefix}wrist_1_link">
  <xacro:get_visual_params name="wrist_1" type="visual_offset"/>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 ${visual_params}" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <xacro:get_mesh name="wrist_1" type="visual"/>
    </geometry>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 ${visual_params}" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <xacro:get_mesh name="wrist_1" type="collision"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  <inertial>
    <mass value="${wrist_1_mass}"/>
        <origin rpy="${wrist_1_inertia_rotation}" xyz="${wrist_1_cog}"/>
        <inertia
            ixx="${wrist_1_inertia_ixx}"
        ixy="${wrist_1_inertia_ixy}"
            ixz="${wrist_1_inertia_ixz}"
        iyy="${wrist_1_inertia_iyy}"
            iyz="${wrist_1_inertia_iyz}"
        izz="${wrist_1_inertia_izz}"
        />
      </inertial>
    </link>
    <link name="${tf_prefix}wrist_2_link">
  <xacro:get_visual_params name="wrist_2" type="visual_offset"/>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 ${visual_params}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <xacro:get_mesh name="wrist_2" type="visual"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${visual_params}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <xacro:get_mesh name="wrist_2" type="collision"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  <inertial>
    <mass value="${wrist_2_mass}"/>
        <origin rpy="${wrist_2_inertia_rotation}" xyz="${wrist_2_cog}"/>
        <inertia
            ixx="${wrist_2_inertia_ixx}"
        ixy="${wrist_2_inertia_ixy}"
            ixz="${wrist_2_inertia_ixz}"
        iyy="${wrist_2_inertia_iyy}"
            iyz="${wrist_2_inertia_iyz}"
        izz="${wrist_2_inertia_izz}"
        />
      </inertial>
    </link>
    <link name="${tf_prefix}wrist_3_link">
  <xacro:get_visual_params name="wrist_3" type="visual_offset"/>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 ${visual_params}" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <xacro:get_mesh name="wrist_3" type="visual"/>
    </geometry>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 ${visual_params}" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <xacro:get_mesh name="wrist_3" type="collision"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  <inertial>
    <mass value="${wrist_3_mass}"/>
        <origin rpy="${wrist_3_inertia_rotation}" xyz="${wrist_3_cog}"/>
        <inertia
            ixx="${wrist_3_inertia_ixx}"
        ixy="${wrist_3_inertia_ixy}"
            ixz="${wrist_3_inertia_ixz}"
        iyy="${wrist_3_inertia_iyy}"
            iyz="${wrist_3_inertia_iyz}"
        izz="${wrist_3_inertia_izz}"
        />
      </inertial>
    </link>

    <!-- base_joint fixes base_link to the environment -->
    <joint name="${tf_prefix}base_joint" type="fixed">
  <xacro:insert_block name="origin" />
  <parent link="${parent}" />
      <child link="${tf_prefix}base_link" />
    </joint> 

    <!-- Disable collision between parent and base link -->
    <!-- <disable_collisions link1="${tf_prefix}base_link" link2="${parent}" /> -->


    <!-- joints - main serial chain -->
    <joint name="${tf_prefix}base_link-base_link_inertia" type="fixed">
  <parent link="${tf_prefix}base_link" />
      <child link="${tf_prefix}base_link_inertia" />
  <!-- 'base_link' is REP-103 aligned (so X+ forward), while the internal
       frames of the robot/controller have X+ pointing backwards.
       Use the joint between 'base_link' and 'base_link_inertia' (a dummy
       link/frame) to introduce the necessary rotation over Z (of pi rad).
  -->
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 ${pi}" />
    </joint>
    <joint name="${tf_prefix}shoulder_pan_joint" type="revolute">
  <parent link="${tf_prefix}base_link_inertia" />
      <child link="${tf_prefix}shoulder_link" />
  <origin xyz="${shoulder_x} ${shoulder_y} ${shoulder_z}" rpy="${shoulder_roll} ${shoulder_pitch} ${shoulder_yaw}" />
  <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
  <limit lower="${shoulder_pan_lower_limit}" upper="${shoulder_pan_upper_limit}"
    effort="${shoulder_pan_effort_limit}" velocity="${shoulder_pan_velocity_limit}"/>
  <xacro:if value="${safety_limits}">
         <safety_controller soft_lower_limit="${shoulder_pan_lower_limit + safety_pos_margin}" soft_upper_limit="${shoulder_pan_upper_limit - safety_pos_margin}" k_position="${safety_k_position}" k_velocity="0.0"/>
  </xacro:if>
  <dynamics damping="0" friction="0"/>
</joint>
<joint name="${tf_prefix}shoulder_lift_joint" type="revolute">
      <parent link="${tf_prefix}shoulder_link" />
  <child link="${tf_prefix}upper_arm_link" />
      <origin xyz="${upper_arm_x} ${upper_arm_y} ${upper_arm_z}" rpy="${upper_arm_roll} ${upper_arm_pitch} ${upper_arm_yaw}" />
      <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
      <limit lower="${shoulder_lift_lower_limit}" upper="${shoulder_lift_upper_limit}"
        effort="${shoulder_lift_effort_limit}" velocity="${shoulder_lift_velocity_limit}"/>
      <xacro:if value="${safety_limits}">
     <safety_controller soft_lower_limit="${shoulder_lift_lower_limit + safety_pos_margin}" soft_upper_limit="${shoulder_lift_upper_limit - safety_pos_margin}" k_position="${safety_k_position}" k_velocity="0.0"/>
      </xacro:if>
      <dynamics damping="0" friction="0"/>
    </joint>
    <joint name="${tf_prefix}elbow_joint" type="revolute">
  <parent link="${tf_prefix}upper_arm_link" />
      <child link="${tf_prefix}forearm_link" />
  <origin xyz="${forearm_x} ${forearm_y} ${forearm_z}" rpy="${forearm_roll} ${forearm_pitch} ${forearm_yaw}" />
  <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
  <limit lower="${elbow_joint_lower_limit}" upper="${elbow_joint_upper_limit}"
    effort="${elbow_joint_effort_limit}" velocity="${elbow_joint_velocity_limit}"/>
  <xacro:if value="${safety_limits}">
         <safety_controller soft_lower_limit="${elbow_joint_lower_limit + safety_pos_margin}" soft_upper_limit="${elbow_joint_upper_limit - safety_pos_margin}" k_position="${safety_k_position}" k_velocity="0.0"/>
  </xacro:if>
  <dynamics damping="0" friction="0"/>
</joint>
<joint name="${tf_prefix}wrist_1_joint" type="revolute">
      <parent link="${tf_prefix}forearm_link" />
  <child link="${tf_prefix}wrist_1_link" />
      <origin xyz="${wrist_1_x} ${wrist_1_y} ${wrist_1_z}" rpy="${wrist_1_roll} ${wrist_1_pitch} ${wrist_1_yaw}" />
      <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
      <limit lower="${wrist_1_lower_limit}" upper="${wrist_1_upper_limit}"
        effort="${wrist_1_effort_limit}" velocity="${wrist_1_velocity_limit}"/>
      <xacro:if value="${safety_limits}">
     <safety_controller soft_lower_limit="${wrist_1_lower_limit + safety_pos_margin}" soft_upper_limit="${wrist_1_upper_limit - safety_pos_margin}" k_position="${safety_k_position}" k_velocity="0.0"/>
      </xacro:if>
      <dynamics damping="0" friction="0"/>
    </joint>
    <joint name="${tf_prefix}wrist_2_joint" type="revolute">
  <parent link="${tf_prefix}wrist_1_link" />
      <child link="${tf_prefix}wrist_2_link" />
  <origin xyz="${wrist_2_x} ${wrist_2_y} ${wrist_2_z}" rpy="${wrist_2_roll} ${wrist_2_pitch} ${wrist_2_yaw}" />
  <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
  <limit lower="${wrist_2_lower_limit}" upper="${wrist_2_upper_limit}"
         effort="${wrist_2_effort_limit}" velocity="${wrist_2_velocity_limit}"/>
  <xacro:if value="${safety_limits}">
         <safety_controller soft_lower_limit="${wrist_2_lower_limit + safety_pos_margin}" soft_upper_limit="${wrist_2_upper_limit - safety_pos_margin}" k_position="${safety_k_position}" k_velocity="0.0"/>
  </xacro:if>
  <dynamics damping="0" friction="0"/>
</joint>
<joint name="${tf_prefix}wrist_3_joint" type="revolute">
      <parent link="${tf_prefix}wrist_2_link" />
  <child link="${tf_prefix}wrist_3_link" />
      <origin xyz="${wrist_3_x} ${wrist_3_y} ${wrist_3_z}" rpy="${wrist_3_roll} ${wrist_3_pitch} ${wrist_3_yaw}" />
      <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
      <limit lower="${wrist_3_lower_limit}" upper="${wrist_3_upper_limit}"
             effort="${wrist_3_effort_limit}" velocity="${wrist_3_velocity_limit}"/>
      <xacro:if value="${safety_limits}">
     <safety_controller soft_lower_limit="${wrist_3_lower_limit + safety_pos_margin}" soft_upper_limit="${wrist_3_upper_limit - safety_pos_margin}" k_position="${safety_k_position}" k_velocity="0.0"/>
      </xacro:if>
      <dynamics damping="0" friction="0"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="${tf_prefix}ft_frame"/>
<joint name="${tf_prefix}wrist_3_link-ft_frame" type="fixed">
      <parent link="${tf_prefix}wrist_3_link"/>
  <child link="${tf_prefix}ft_frame"/>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi} 0 0"/>
    </joint>

    <!-- ROS-Industrial 'base' frame - base_link to UR 'Base' Coordinates transform -->
    <link name="${tf_prefix}base"/>
<joint name="${tf_prefix}base_link-base_fixed_joint" type="fixed">
      <!-- Note the rotation over Z of pi radians - as base_link is REP-103
           aligned (i.e., has X+ forward, Y+ left and Z+ up), this is needed
           to correctly align 'base' with the 'Base' coordinate system of
           the UR controller.
      -->
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 ${pi}"/>
  <parent link="${tf_prefix}base_link"/>
      <child link="${tf_prefix}base"/>
    </joint>

    <!-- ROS-Industrial 'flange' frame - attachment point for EEF models -->
    <link name="${tf_prefix}flange" />
<joint name="${tf_prefix}wrist_3-flange" type="fixed">
      <parent link="${tf_prefix}wrist_3_link" />
  <child link="${tf_prefix}flange" />
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 ${-pi/2.0} ${-pi/2.0}" />
    </joint>

    <!-- Adding the welding_tool  -->
    <link name="${tf_prefix}tool0">
<xacro:get_visual_params name="tool0" type="visual_offset"/>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 ${visual_params}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <xacro:get_mesh name="tool0" type="visual"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${visual_params}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <xacro:get_mesh name="tool0" type="collision"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    
    <joint name="${tf_prefix}flange-tool0" type="fixed">
  <!-- default toolframe - X+ left, Y+ up, Z+ front -->
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2.0} 0 ${pi/2.0}"/>
  <parent link="${tf_prefix}flange"/>
      <child link="${tf_prefix}tool0"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="${tf_prefix}zivid">
<xacro:get_visual_params name="zivid" type="visual_offset"/>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 ${visual_params}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <xacro:get_mesh name="zivid" type="visual"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${visual_params}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <xacro:get_mesh name="zivid" type="collision"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>

    <joint name="${tf_prefix}zivid-tool0" type="fixed">
  <!-- default toolframe - X+ left, Y+ up, Z+ front -->
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="${tf_prefix}tool0"/>
      <child link="${tf_prefix}zivid"/>
</joint>
<!-- Disable collision between zivid and tool0 -->
<disable_collisions link1="${tf_prefix}zivid" link2="${tf_prefix}tool0" />



  </xacro:macro>
</robot>




Please explain more clearly what error you are having (with exact text, if any). Your current description is confusing because gazebo-classic does not create a collision between the parent/child links which are connected by a joint.

First, there is no error text, simulation and rviz are launching correctly without putting any error in the shell.
I try to put  a new object to the scene through the ur_macro.xacro file, such as a camera for exemple, I have not succed to diseable collision between camera and the robot (Rviz showing red on camera and robot last wrist).
To overcome this issue I have seen that in the natif code, there were a specific section for us to put our EE in the scene, named 'tool0'. Now my welding tool do not collide with the rest of the robot. How add another object now, and make it not collide ?

Please do not ask a new question within the answer to a prior question. Instead, you should create a new question. In the new question, you can include a link to this page if you think it provides helpful context.

Also, if the original question here received a good/helpful answer (even if you answered it yourself), then you should click the gray checkmark to the left of that answer to tell us it solved the problem. The checkmark will change to green.

Thank you @Mike973, I open a new subject about the specific issue of disabling collision (Cf New_question). Moreover, as the question of the EE has been resolved, I will checkmark this one. Ty !
